# Is it better to limit access to Firebase by being authenticated or not?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I've already read on a lot of topics that it was impossible to completely secure our server (people could always get the server address and use it themselves).

But what I would like to do is to limit this risk.  So here's my question : could restricting access to my server only to authenticated users "make it harder" for people who use my server with their own apps/website (not mine) ?

And also, if the answer is no, what would you choose between leaving write/read access open to everyone or allowing only authenticated people to do so?

Thank you!

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking.  What does it mean for someone to "use your server"? You can certainly use authentication to check to see if the user is who they say they are, but it's entirely up to you to decide if they can do what they want.  Your code, your policy.  Please edit the question to be more clear.

Comment: What I means by someone uses my server is for example someone who know my server address and use it with his own app/website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People will always be able to find your database info because it is included with the app. You can protect your self from that by using **firebase security rules** (and firebase authentication).

To put it plainly firebase security rules say who has **access** and what he **can do** (create, read, update, delete). They can be simple eg (only authenticated users can write) or more complex eg (only the creator of the document or node can read it). With firebase security rules you can also validate what data you receive.

If firebase rules are enforced correctly I don't think that you will have any problem. But how they must be enforced in your app depend's on your app's needs.

Check out the firebase security rules documentation [link 1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security), the firebase security rules for realtime database [link 2](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) and this article about them [link 3](https://fireship.io/snippets/firestore-rules-recipes/)

Comment: Don't answer clearly the question... So is it better (more security) to need to be authenticated to read/write to my server or not?

Comment: Yes, but you must not simply use if the user is authenticated or not to check if he can have access. You must add more complex security rules to provide better security.